# Selenium: How to wait for a element's text to change

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have an element whose status (in text form) changes depending on a contextmenu associated with it.
Here is the element:

```
td id="A" name="status"> StatusStart  </td>
```

Upon some action, this can become

```
 td id="A" name="status"> StatusDone  </td>
```

I want to wait for the text change to happen, using waitForCondition.
So far, i've tried:

```
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"//td[@name='status' and text()='StatusDone']\");", "10000");
```

but that doesn't work because the text is not part of the td element.
In JavaScript, i see something like:

```
function myfunc() {        
window.getGlobal().addSelectGroup('status'); window.getGlobal().addSelectItem('status','StatusStart');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a repetitive `storeText(css=td[name=status],var_name)` within a do-while ([java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)) loop and `break` once `var_name="StatusDone"`

Answer (score 4):

Please try to change xpath as follows.

```
//td[@name='status' and .//text()='StatusDone']
```

or

```
//td[@name='status' and contains(.//text(),'StatusDone')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "that doesn't work because the text is not part of the td element".  Which is odd, because the HTML you show says that the text **is** part of the TD element.  And the `waitForCondition()` you've tried is exactly the way to do it.  My best guess is that the TD text is not **exactly** "StatusDone", but rather " StatusDone  " (based on your HTML).  The comparison will never match if so.  There are obvious ways to fix that - add the spaces to the constant, or use `contains(text(), 'StatusDone')` instead of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit wait?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```